# how to remove this error from intelliJ console flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, intellij-idea, console, flutter-layout

I am getting this annoying line from IntelliJ console

```
D/EGL_emulation(10800): app_time_stats: avg=339.24ms min=32.73ms max=584.59ms count=3
```

can anyone tell me how to remove this line from printing as I am using IntelliJ idea

[image]

Comment: Why do you want to remove it? This doesn't seem like an error.

Comment: i have add picture of it so you can see why i want this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right click and choose 'Fold Lines Like This'.

Comment: it works brother I want to add something: just add this in fold lines (D/EGL_emulation), not full line as app time stats changing with every line

Comment: Very good, thank you, this should be the approved answer.